# Posix Threads attributes & detach state

Tags: c, attributes, pthreads, posix

Today I came across POSIX thread attributes, they are a little weird work with, when you are using them for the first time. I am a little confused about `pthread_attr_setdetachstate`, which states that:

> POSIX threads are in Join state (with the thread which created it) by default but in order to join them, we have to explicitly call `pthread_join()` for joining the thread.

Do we need to call `pthread_detach` explicitly even when the thread attribute is set to `detach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you even shouldn't do that:

> Attempting to detach an already detached thread results in unspecified
>   behavior.

So really do either one of them but not both. If you know from the start that you wouldn't joint the thread, use the variant with the attribute. Depending on your system this might save up some time and memory at the startup of your thread.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Either one or the other will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to call `pthread_detach()` explicitly even when the thread attribute is set to detach?

No, it's not necessary, [here's an illustration](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/joinable-and-detached-threads/). Both methods (either creating the thread as detached or `pthread_detach()`ing it) works fine.

Comment: if we explicitly set thread attribute as joined, do we still need to call pthread_join to join it with parent thread(the thread which created it).

Comment: @Alfred: There is no attribute as `...JOINED`. There only is `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE`. And yes, if a threads detach state had been set to joinable, you shall call `pthread_join()` to have it joined, and with that cleaned up the resources in use by this thread.